# Enter each value in a range of data as its own line in an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to email a range of cells.

I get an email with every value one after the other.

I would like each cell as its own line.

Previously I had it inputting each cell individually but I was getting a contiguous line error.

```vb
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    'Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
    strbody = build_body(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B45:C65")) & vbNewLine & _
      "2nd Shift Trippers" & vbNewLine & _
      build_body(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("f45:g65"))
                `your text`  
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "namen@somewhere.org"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Date & vbCrLf & "Trippers"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
        
End Sub

   
Function build_body(rng As Range, Optional delimiter As String = " ") As String
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim tmpStr As String
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If tmpStr <> "" Then tmpStr = tmpStr & delimiter & cel.Value
        If tmpStr = "" Then tmpStr = cel.Value
    Next cel
    Debug.Print tmpStr
    build_body = tmpStr
End Function
```

Comment: "cells to output into the email as there own line" it could help to upload a pic of your desired result

Comment: `If tmpStr <> "" Then tmpStr = tmpStr & vbNewLine & cel.Value`

Answer (score 0):

The values of the cells need to be separated by vbNewLine.

You are calling the Function build_body which takes 2 arguments: a range of cells and a delimiter. To separate each cell with a new line, use the delimiter "vbNewLine".

```
strbody = build_body(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B45:C65")) & vbNewLine & _
"2nd Shift Trippers" & vbNewLine & _
          build_body(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("f45:g65"), vbNewLine)
        `your text`
```